# English "are/is" or "you/we"

Tags: grammar

I want to paint a picture that uses the quote "love and prayers".
Should I say "all we need are love and prayers" or "all you need is love and prayers" or "all we need is love and prayers"?

Answer (score -1):

All we need is love and prayers. I guess you could use you instead of we but you   doesn't suit the intent. Using you sounds a bit condescending.